# "You need local access to create the initial admin user" error while keycloak startup in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, keycloak

While starting keycloak server on docker, I am getting this error: "You need local access to create the initial admin user". But running it locally, it's working fine.

Another thing is that if I want to use Postgres db instead of embedded H2 db then should I create tables to store user, clients and scope, etc? If yes how can I get db structure for all tables?

[image: You need local access to create the initial admin user]

Answer (score 28):

You can let the container create the admin user by providing the environment variables `KEYCLOAK_USER` and `KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD`:

```sh
docker run -e KEYCLOAK_USER=<USERNAME> -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD> jboss/keycloak
```

Or add the account to an existing container( Service or container restart required afterwards) with:

```sh
docker exec <CONTAINER> /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD>
```

And either restart container
`docker restart <container>`

Or restart the service (@Madeo's answer)

`docker exec -it <container> /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command=:reload`

The above commands come from the [Keycloak Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) page on Docker Hub.

Regarding your database question, you don't have to provide the tables by hand.
You can refer to chapter [6](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_installation/#_database) ([§6.4](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_installation/#modify-the-keycloak-datasource), [§6.5](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_installation/#database-configuration)) of the [Keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_installation/) for the details of how to configure a PostgreSQL DB.

Comment: The `add-user-keycloak.sh` will say "Added 'admin' to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json', restart server to load user". So it may be not that useful for stateless containers such as in kubernetes.

Comment: If using Kubernetes the using environment variables is more convinient. I deployed using helm and provided user and password in extraVars. @ch271828n

Comment: @Madeo - the linked [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) suggests to restart the container. Allthough I find your suggested approach more convienent, i will edit my answer propperly

Comment: This answer seems deprecated. [Replacement for add-user-keycloak.sh | Github](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10302) - Apparently the `add-user-keycloak.sh` bin is no longer available since Keycloak 17.

Answer (score 8):

- Open container bash console

```sh
cd /keycloak/bin
bash ./add-user-keycloak.sh -u admin
```

- Enter desired password
- Restart the container
- Go to following URL for login

```
http://dockerIP:8080/auth/admin/
```

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: „*…Open container bash console…*“  – @kannetkeifer — Your answer is helpful. But only partially so. That's because you omit the most important (*and least-obvious*) step in the process: «***How to enter the container to run the bash console?***». [*Keycloak docker images are implemented*](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/dockerfile) with a particular combination of  *`ENTRYPOINT`* and *`CMD`* instructions such that the *usual* *`docker run -it…/bin/sh`* command errors out. So step #1 ***should*** be: *`docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:11.0.2`*.

Comment: Seems outdated: [Replacement for add-user-keycloak.sh | Github](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10302) - Apparently the `add-user-keycloak.sh` bin is no longer available since Keycloak 17.

Answer (score 6):

None of the tips above worked. Finally I use Environment Variables:

```
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
```

The full code of the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
      driver: local

services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.1
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: postgres
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
        KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
        KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      entrypoint: ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev"]
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - postgres
```

Comment: Note that the environment variables have been renamed since version 17. Previously th variables were `KEYCLOAK_USER` and `KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD`. From version 17 they are `KEYCLOAK_ADMIN` and `KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD`.

Comment: @MichielLeegwater Thanks for sharing this update! There are a ton of tutorials out there that don't make this distinction, GPT included. I'm finally able to see the admin view.

Answer (score 5):

For Keycloak 17, you can use `lynx` locally to create the admin user:

```sh
lynx localhost:8080
```

Then just <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate fields and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the `Create` button:

```
   Keycloak

Welcome to Keycloak

[user.png] Administration Console

   Please create an initial admin user to get started.

   Username ____________________

   Password ____________________

   Password confirmation ____________________
   (BUTTON) Create

[user.png] Administration Console

   Centrally manage all aspects of the Keycloak server

[admin-console.png] Documentation

   User Guide, Admin REST API and Javadocs

[keycloak-project.png] Keycloak Project

[mail.png] Mailing List

[bug.png] Report an issue

   JBoss and JBoss Community
```

Comment: Keycloak 20.0.1

`You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.`
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer with docker is incomplete and it won't work

If you add the user via docker container you **must restart jboss server**

```
docker exec -it keycloak-container /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh -u admin -p admin
```

and then:

```
docker exec -it keycloak-container /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command=:reload
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
cd /opt/keycloak/bin 
sudo ./add-user-keycloak.sh -u admin -p yourpass
```

Answer (score 0):

Open 'keycloak.conf' file from Keycloak folder (in my case keycloak-18.0.0/conf)

```
db-username=postgres

db-password=password

db-url=jdbc:postgresql://yourhostname:5432/keycloak-db-name
```

If you start keycloak service, postgres DB will be created automatically

Answer (score 0):

Using the Operator https://www.keycloak.org/guides#operator, I had the same issue.

The username and password provided by this step

```
kubectl get secret example-kc-initial-admin -o jsonpath='{.data.username}' | base64 --decode
kubectl get secret example-kc-initial-admin -o jsonpath='{.data.password}' | base64 --decode
```

https://www.keycloak.org/operator/basic-deployment#_accessing_the_keycloak_deployment
did not work.

What apparently solved it for me was deleting all Keycloak CRs, deployments, services, etc. and starting the tutorial from the beginning. Then, I omitted this optional step:

> We suggest you to first store the Database credentials in a separate Secret, you can do it for example by running:

```
kubectl create secret generic keycloak-db-secret \
  --from-literal=username=[your_database_username] \
  --from-literal=password=[your_database_password]
```

(with made up Postgres username and password filling in the brackets)

I am not sure how the Database secret relates to the Admin User secret, but now the username and password in `example-kc-initial-admin` work. Perhaps Postgres was inaccessible to Keycloak. This was not indicated in the Keycloak logs.

I don't believe starting fresh was the solution, because I already tried that. Omitting `keycloak-db-secret` seems to have been important. I will need to fully understand where the DB secret is set, now; it may be insecure.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a reference of the command that finally worked for me. Note that I'm connecting from keycloak container to local postgres. I don't use docker-compose for now neither postgres in a container. Adjust according to your needs.

```
podman run --name app-auth \
-p 8080:8080 \
-e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin \
-e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=1234 \
-e KC_DB=postgres \
-e KC_DB_URL_HOST=host.docker.internal \
-e KC_DB_URL_PORT=5432 \
-e KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=app-auth \
-e KC_DB_USERNAME=postgres \
-e KC_DB_PASSWORD=1234 \
-e KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true \
-e KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true \
-e QUARKUS_HTTP_ACCESS_LOG_ENABLED=true \
quay.io/keycloak/keycloak start-dev
```

Note, I'm using the alias to access postgres from host. You will need to replace it with your own bridge network if you are using postgres from a container.

- Docker Host Alias - `host.docker.internal`
- Podman Host Alias - `host.containers.internal`